# How to display in a curent page an external image in base64 (atob)

Tags: javascript, image, hyperlink, base64

I am actually working in the "Legal Mentions page" of client site.
He would like to display it under a full image (not text) hostend in a external site, but encoded in base64 (not a simple link https://...).

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,aHR0cHM6Ly9jZG4uc3N0YXRpYy5uZXQvSW1nL3RlYW1zL3RlYW1zLWlsbG8tZnJlZS1zaWRlYmFyLXByb21vLnN2Zz92PTQ3ZmFhNjU5YTA1ZQ==">`

This is not working...

`<a href="#" onload='this.href=atob("aHR0cHM6Ly9jZG4uc3N0YXRpYy5uZXQvSW1nL3RlYW1zL3RlYW1zLWlsbG8tZnJlZS1zaWRlYmFyLXByb21vLnN2Zz92PTQ3ZmFhNjU5YTA1ZQ==")'></a> -->`

This works but it's a link, I don't want this but a loading.

I try many things and nothing works for me.

Could someone just put me on a track.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data:image/png;base64,aHR0cHM6Ly9jZG4uc3N0YXRpYy5uZXQvSW1nL3RlYW1zL3RlYW1zLWlsbG8tZnJlZS1zaWRlYmFyLXByb21vLnN2Zz92PTQ3ZmFhNjU5YTA1ZQ==
```

Is a data URI. That means that it should contain actual (image) data and not a link to an image. Right now it contains a base64 encoded link.
Take the image that you want to display and convert it (for example via an online converter) to Base64 and insert the Base64 string in your data URI.

Example (showing a red dot, example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Examples_of_use)):

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA
ANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU
5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Comment: I understand, thank you. It it possible to encode a link to call an extrernal image.

exemple :

I trying to convert this : 

`<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e">`

into something like this :

`<img src="aHR0cHM6Ly9jZG4uc3N0YXRpYy5uZXQvSW1nL3RlYW1zL3RlYW1zLWlsbG8tZnJlZS1zaWRlYmFyLXByb21vLnN2Zz92PTQ3ZmFhNjU5YTA1ZQ==">`

Comment: converting the picture is not a solution because we need to update it in several sites. That's why the picture is an external ressource. If we change the picture then the picture will update everywhere.

Comment: I see, I probably misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

**1 Distant server**
Instead of calling my external image by url and trying to convert it in base64 from my website, I created a .txt file which contains already the image encoded (like mentionned by jps).

**2 Back to my site**
I just called the .txt distant file with file_get_contents function :

```php
<php

$external_image_base64 = file_get_contents("https://exemple.com/images/myfilename.txt");<br>
img src="<php echo $external_image_base64; ?>"

?>
```

Now everytime I need to update my image, I just need to convert the new one and paste it on the distant file.